# Handle Multiple request in Android volley

Tags: android, performance, android-volley

I am trying to hit multiple request using Volley and i am getting response for all the request. my problem is how to identify the response is belong to which API.

```
mQueue = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
            .getRequestQueue();

    final CustomJSONObjectrequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectrequest(Request.Method
            .GET, url,
            new JSONObject(), this, this); // 
    jsonRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);

    final CustomJSONObjectrequest jsonRequest2 = new CustomJSONObjectrequest(Request.Method
            .GET, url2,
            new JSONObject(), this, this);
    jsonRequest2.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
            mQueue.add(jsonRequest2); // Both the request will have different API request
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText(error.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Object response) {

    // How to identify, which response is belong to which api request
    mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this for a single request. Same can be applied to the second request. This way you know which request is giving you the response.

```
final CustomJSONObjectrequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectrequest(Request.Method
        .GET, url,
        new JSONObject(), this,  new Response.Listener<Object>() {
                @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {

// How to identify, which response is belong to which api request
mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response);

});
```

**EDITED :**

You can start with making an interface like :

```
public interface VolleyResponse {

void onResponse(JSONObject object, String tag);

void onError(VolleyError error, String tag);
}
```

Then you can make a custom handler for volley request like:

```
public class CustomJSONObjectRequest implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

private VolleyResponse volleyResponse;
private String tag;
private JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;


public CustomJSONObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonObject, String tag, VolleyResponse volleyResponse) {
    this.volleyResponse = volleyResponse;
    this.tag= tag;
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, jsonObject, this, this);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    volleyResponse.onResponse(response, tag);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    volleyResponse.onError(error, tag);
}

public JsonObjectRequest getJsonObjectRequest() {
    return jsonObjectRequest;
}
}
```

And to call it in your class use it like:

```
 CustomJSONObjectRequest request1 = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new JSONObject(), "YOUR REQUEST TAG", this);
```

Make sure to let your class implement the `VolleyResponse` interface that will get you the response and your tag.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject object, String tag) {
    Log.i("Response :", object.toString() + "   " + tag);
}

@Override
public void onError(VolleyError error, String tag) {

}
```

To add the request to the volley queue you can use:

```
mQueue.add(request1.getJsonObjectRequest());
```

PS : this code is not tested but it should work.

Comment: if i implement Response.Listener in my parent class and i will override OnResponse method in my parent.then  is there any way to identify using Tag or anything else ?

Comment: You can make an abstract class that implements the `Response.Listener` interface and make it take two parameters , the second one being the tag.

Comment: i am doing that way only. but in OnResponse(Obj), had one parameter only. then how we identify the TAG for request or if i am wrong can explain  little bit more.

Comment: i tried to do a make a custom class for request handling. didnt get to test it but it should work fine.

Comment: can you share it? if possible .then it could be help me lot

Answer (score 5):

Create a Generic Volley class and a Interface, Use the interface to get success and failure responds.

- Step 1 Create a separate Volley class
- Step 2 Create a interface for accessing the response  from volley class
- Step 3 create new object for
  the class and send required parameters

> new PostVolleyJsonRequest(TestVolley.this, TestVolley.this(interfcae), "Submit", url, params);

1. Context of the class
2. Interface for sending Success and failure responds
3. Type of request to identify on success
4. url (mandatory)
5. Param (optional) for GET no need

Generic volley class

```
public class PostVolleyJsonRequest {
private String  type;
private Activity act;
private VolleyJsonRespondsListener volleyJsonRespondsListener;
private String networkurl;
private JSONObject jsonObject = null;
private JSONObject params;


public PostVolleyJsonRequest(Activity act, VolleyJsonRespondsListener volleyJsonRespondsListener, String type, String netnetworkUrl,JSONObject params) {
    this.act = act;
    this.volleyJsonRespondsListener = volleyJsonRespondsListener;
    this.type = type;
    this.networkurl = netnetworkUrl;
    this.params = params;
    sendRequest();
}

private void sendRequest() {

    Log.d("url", "url" + networkurl);
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,networkurl,params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("response", "response " + response);
                    volleyJsonRespondsListener.onSuccessJson(response, type);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    try {
                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                        Log.e("response", "response " + response);
                        if (response != null) {
                            int code = response.statusCode;

                            String errorMsg = new String(response.data);
                            Log.e("response", "response" + errorMsg);
                            try {
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(errorMsg);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String msg = jsonObject.optString("message");
                            volleyJsonRespondsListener.onFailureJson(code, msg);
                        } else {
                            String errorMsg = error.getMessage();
                            volleyJsonRespondsListener.onFailureJson(0, errorMsg);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            600000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(act);
    requestqueue.add(jsObjRequest);

}
```

}

Use the interface to get responds message

```
public interface VolleyJsonRespondsListener {

public void onSuccessJson(JSONObject result, String type);
public void onFailureJson(int responseCode, String responseMessage);
```

}

In your class where you want to include multiple request

```
public class TestVolley extends AppCompatActivity implements VolleyJsonRespondsListener{

//Your class code goes here


//network request

try {
        //parameters 
        //Context,Interface,Type(to indentify your responds),URL,parameter for your request 

        //request 1
        new PostVolleyJsonRequest(TestVolley.this, TestVolley.this, "Submit", url, params);

        //request 2
        new PostVolleyJsonRequest(TestVolley.this, TestVolley.this, "AccessData", url_2, params_2);




 } catch (Exception e) {

 e.printStackTrace()
 }

 //Methods from Interface

  @Override
public void onSuccessJson(JSONObject result, String type) {

   //Based on the Type you send get the responds and parse it 
    switch (type) {
        case "Submit":
            try {
                parseSubmit(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "AccessData":
            try {
                parseAccessData(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           break;
    }
```