# Passing data to an Interface from Volley onResponse() isn't working

Tags: android, interface, android-volley

I'm fetching multiple API's data by using a single [Volley](http://www.example.com/) library. For this, I made a generic Volley class and I'm calling this class form an activity by passing required parameters. And I successfully did this.

After this, The response I'm getting from server, want to pass it to an Interface in order to get result to the same class from which I'm calling generic Volley class. But I'm not able to do this.
I know the problem is in my function call. But I don't know how to resolve it.

Also, I'm using his technique [Handle Multiple request in Android volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212853/handle-multiple-request-in-android-volley)  *2nd answer*

> Here's my interface

```
public interface VolleyJsonRespondsListener{

    public  void onSuccessJson(String result, String type);
}
```

> Here's my generic volley class

```
public class PostVolleyJsonRequest {

    Context context;
    Map<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
    private VolleyJsonRespondsListener volleyJsonRespondsListener;
    private String networkurl;


    public PostVolleyJsonRequest(Context context, String netnetworkUrl, Map<String, String> hashMap, VolleyJsonRespondsListener volleyJsonRespondsListener) {
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
        this.networkurl = netnetworkUrl;
        this.volleyJsonRespondsListener = volleyJsonRespondsListener;
        this.context=context;
        sendRequest();
    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, networkurl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("result", response);
                        volleyJsonRespondsListener.onSuccessJson(response, "sub"); //here's the error

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("result", "error " + error);
                        error.printStackTrace();
                                         }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return hashMap;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        /*handle timeout error*/
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

> Here's my activity from which am calling function and want to get server response through interface

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements VolleyJsonRespondsListener {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

  new PostVolleyJsonRequest(context, CommonObjects.API_LOGIN, hashMap, ); //here to do something

    }

 @Override
    public void onSuccessJson(String result, String type) {
        Log.i("resultRespone", result);


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailureJson(int responseCode, String responseMessage) {

    }
}
```

> Logcat

```
2019-07-31 14:35:05.703 9401-9401/com.amcbr.amcbradmin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.amcbr.amcbradmin, PID: 9401
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.amcbr.amcbradmin.classes.utils.VolleyJsonRespondsListener.onSuccessJson(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.amcbr.amcbradmin.classes.utils.PostVolleyJsonRequest$1.onResponse(PostVolleyJsonRequest.java:102)
        at com.amcbr.amcbradmin.classes.utils.PostVolleyJsonRequest$1.onResponse(PostVolleyJsonRequest.java:98)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pass the listener properly in your `Login` Activity, it should be like this:

```
new PostVolleyJsonRequest(context, CommonObjects.API_LOGIN, hashMap, Login.this);
```

Comment: I can't pass ```this```as param. because of different data type of function call and at receiving end as

```volleyJsonRespondsListener:
com...utils.VolleyJsonRespondsListener
this  (anonymous...view.View.OnClickListener)```

Comment: Pass it in your Login class and try writing `Login.this` if you are making this request in a click listener.