# Android rest api call

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley to get data from an API. In that API some data are represented as "id". For that, I need to do another API call inside the response of the previous API call. Is there any way to call each API calls as separate method calls and use only the return value of each call in the `onViewCreated()` method?

Here is the URL

```
String liveURL = BASE_URL + "fixtures/date/" + dateFormat +"?api_token=" + API_KEY;
```

and respective code block for response

```
JsonObjectRequest livescoresRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        liveURL, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Log.d("Live", response.toString());
            try {
              final JSONArray liveArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

              for (int i = 0; i < liveArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject data = liveArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String liveID = data.getString("id");
                final String league_id = data.getString("league_id");
                final String localteam_id = data.getString("localteam_id");

                String leagueURL = BASE_URL + "leagues/" + league_id + "?api_token=" + API_KEY;

                JsonObjectRequest leaguesRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        leagueURL, null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                          @Override
                          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                              JSONObject leaguesArray = response.getJSONObject("data");
                              String length = String.valueOf(response.length());

                              final String leagueName = leaguesArray.getString("name");
                              final String leagueLogo = leaguesArray.getString("logo_path");
                              Log.d("Logo", leagueLogo);

                              // GET LOCAL TEAM BY ID
                              String localURL = BASE_URL + "teams/" + localteam_id + "?api_token=" + API_KEY;

                              JsonObjectRequest localRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                                      localURL, null,
                                      new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                          //Log.d("Live", response.toString());
                                          try {
                                            JSONObject leaguesArray = response.getJSONObject("data");
                                            //JSONObject scores = leaguesArray.getJSONObject("scores");

                                            final String localName = leaguesArray.getString("name");

                                            //GET VISITOR BY ID
                                            String visitorURL = BASE_URL + "teams/" + visitorteam_id + "?api_token=" + API_KEY;

                                            JsonObjectRequest visitorRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                                                    visitorURL, null,
                                                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                                      @Override
                                                      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                                        //Log.d("Live", response.toString());
                                                        try {
                                                          JSONObject leaguesArray = response.getJSONObject("data");
                                                          final String visitorName = leaguesArray.getString("name");
                                                          final String localScores = localScore;
                                                          final String visitorScores = visitorScore;
                                                          final String minutes = minute;
                                                          final String willStarts = willStart.substring(0, willStart.length() - 3);

                                                          //GET LOGO FROM IMAGE REQUEST
                                                          ImageRequest logoRequest = new ImageRequest(leagueLogo,
                                                                  new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                                                                    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                                                                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                                                                      //fetching.dismiss();
                                                                      final ExpansionHeader expansionHeader = createExpansionHeader(leagueName, response);
                                                                      expansionHeader.setToggleOnClick(true);
                                                                      expansionHeader.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                                                      dynamicLayoutContainer.addView(expansionHeader, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                                                                      final ExpansionLayout expansionLayout = new ExpansionLayout(getContext());

                                                                      final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                                                                      layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                                                      expansionLayout.addView(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPx(getContext(), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                                                                      layout.addView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_expanded_layout, layout, false));

                                                                      TextView minutesPlaying = layout.findViewById(R.id.minutes);
                                                                      TextView local = layout.findViewById(R.id.localTeam);
                                                                      TextView visitor = layout.findViewById(R.id.visitorTeam);
                                                                      TextView localScore = layout.findViewById(R.id.localTeamScore);
                                                                      TextView visitorScore = layout.findViewById(R.id.visitorTeamScore);

                                                                      if (minutes == "null") {
                                                                        minutesPlaying.setText(willStarts + "\nUTC");
                                                                      } else {
                                                                        minutesPlaying.setText(minutes + "'");
                                                                      }
                                                                      local.setText(localName);
                                                                      visitor.setText(visitorName);
                                                                      localScore.setText(localScores);
                                                                      visitorScore.setText(visitorScores);

                                                                      dynamicLayoutContainer.addView(expansionLayout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                                                      expansionHeader.setExpansionLayout(expansionLayout);
                                                                    }
                                                                  }, 50, 50, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                              error.printStackTrace();
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                          Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(logoRequest);

                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                          e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                      @Override
                                                      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                        Log.d("Error", error.toString());
                                                      }
                                                    });
                                            Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(visitorRequest);

                                          } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                          }
                                        }
                                      },
                                      new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                          Log.d("Error", error.toString());
                                        }
                                      });
                              Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(localRequest);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("Error", error.toString());
                          }
                        });
                Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(leaguesRequest);

              }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", error.toString());
          }
        });
Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(livescoresRequest);`
```

Comment: Can you please share your `onResponsemethod` of the first request?

Comment: Question is edited. Please check it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45213076/9832121

you can do like this. and in response using **YOUR REQUEST TAG** you can handle second response

Comment: @Hardikraiyani I have tried your suggestion and how can I create an instance for the queue? In `mQueue.add(request1.getJsonObjectRequest());` coding how to create mQueue?

Comment: RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request1);

Comment: The above code give the following error > `Make 'CustomJSONObjectRequest' extends 'com.android.volley.request'`

Comment: CustomJSONObjectRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse>